# I need help creating a while loop without altering the scope of a variable

Tags: java

Basically I am creating an extremely basic stock market simulator. The user has a choice between a basic account or an expert account. The basic account has a deposit cap of £500.

I want to create a while loop that will allow the user to keep entering a deposit number until it meets the requirements of it being less than or equal to 500. The while loop will go around the last set of if statements before the Account object is created.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StockMarketInvestor 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Shares Intel = new Shares(120.0, 140.0);
    Shares Sony = new Shares(105.0, 123.0);
    Shares Microsoft = new Shares(240.0, 265.0);
    Shares Google = new Shares(260.0, 303.0);

    System.out.println("Would you like a basic or expert account?");
    System.out.println("1: Basic (deposit capped at £500)");
    System.out.println("2: Expert (unlimited deposit)");

    int accountChoice = input.nextInt();

    if (accountChoice == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("You have chosen a basic account");
    }

    else if (accountChoice == 2)
    {
        System.out.println("You have chosen an expert account");
    }

    System.out.println("How much £ would you like to begin with in the format of £0000.00?");

    double startMoney = input.nextDouble();

    if (accountChoice == 1 && startMoney <=500.0)
    {
        System.out.println("You have chosen to deposit £" + startMoney);
    }

    else if (accountChoice == 1 && startMoney >500.0)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry you can only deposit a max of £500.0");
    }

    AccountBasic PrimaryAccount = new AccountBasic(startMoney);
```

This is the while loop i have tried:

```
 while (true) {
    double startMoney = input.nextDouble();

    if (accountChoice == 1 && startMoney <=500.0)
    {
        System.out.println("You have chosen to deposit £" + startMoney);
    }

    else if (accountChoice == 1 && startMoney >500.0)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry you can only deposit a max of £500.0");
    }
    }

    AccountBasic PrimaryAccount = new AccountBasic(startMoney);
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Show us your `while` that didn't work.

Comment: while (true) {
     double startMoney = input.nextDouble();
     
     if (accountChoice == 1 && startMoney <=500.0)
     {
      System.out.println("You have chosen to deposit £" + startMoney);
     }
     
     else if (accountChoice == 1 && startMoney >500.0)
     {
      System.out.println("Sorry you can only deposit a max of £500.0");
     }
     }
     
     AccountBasic PrimaryAccount = new AccountBasic(startMoney);

Comment: that doesnt work as i get the error "startMoney cannot be resolved to a variable" when i initialize the new Account object

Comment: Please edit your question. It's impossible to read the code in the comment.

Comment: i just posted it in the original question at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You can write following while loop. You can declare the primaryAccount outside the loop but it will be only initialized when you get a valid value from user.
Also, in your statement, initialization should be in a block where you are getting a valid value otherwise you anyways don't have any other value to initialize it.

```
AccountBasic PrimaryAccount;

    while (true) {

        System.out.println("How much £ would you like to begin with in the format of £0000.00?");

        double startMoney = input.nextDouble();

        if (accountChoice == 1 && startMoney <= 500.0) {
            System.out.println("You have chosen to deposit £" + startMoney);
             PrimaryAccount = new AccountBasic(startMoney);
            break;
        } else if (accountChoice == 1 && startMoney > 500.0) {
            System.out.println("Sorry you can only deposit a max of £500.0");
        }
    }
```

Comment: hi thanks for that. but i still get the error PrimaryAccount cannot be resolved.

Comment: did you declared primaryAccount outside the while loop and initialize it inside the loop? If yes, you wont get error.

Answer (score 0):

There's no law that a variable's declaration has to initialize it to a "useful" value right then and there.  So, just *declare* `startMoney` **outside** (before) the loop with a token initializer.  Then instead of declaring and initializing it **inside** the loop, just *assign* it, like this:

```
double startMoney = 0;
while (true) {
    System.out.print("How much....");
    startMoney = input.nextDouble();
    if (startMoney > 0 && startMoney <= 500)
        break;
    System.out.println("Please choose a valid  start amount £1-£500");
}
// Now this still works because startMoney lives outside the loop
AccountBasic PrimaryAccount = new AccountBasic(startMoney);
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to properly use `continue` and `break` statements

- Use `continue` to jump to start of while loop when requirement does
  not meet
- Use `break` to come out of while loop when requirement meets

Following code should do what you want

```
public class StockMarketInvestor {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Shares Intel = new Shares(120.0, 140.0);
    Shares Sony = new Shares(105.0, 123.0);
    Shares Microsoft = new Shares(240.0, 265.0);
    Shares Google = new Shares(260.0, 303.0);

    System.out.println("Would you like a basic or expert account?");
    System.out.println("1: Basic (deposit capped at £500)");
    System.out.println("2: Expert (unlimited deposit)");

    int accountChoice = input.nextInt();

    if (accountChoice == 1) {
      System.out.println("You have chosen a basic account");
    } else if (accountChoice == 2) {
      System.out.println("You have chosen an expert account");
    }

    System.out.println("How much £ would you like to begin with in the format of £0000.00?");

    double startMoney = input.nextDouble();


    while (true) {
     if (accountChoice == 1 && startMoney > 500.0) {
        System.out.println("Sorry you can only deposit a max of £500.0");
        continue;
     }
     System.out.println("You have chosen to deposit £" + startMoney);
     break;
    }

    AccountBasic PrimaryAccount = new AccountBasic(startMoney);
  }
}
```